# validar un array en js

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, validación, booleano

es un login de cedulas de indentidad tipo submit en el html.

este es mi codigo js

```
document.querySelector('#aaceder').addEventListener('click',validacioon);

let datos = ["25000111", "21000222", "22444333", "23222333", "25111222"];
```

en esta funcion es donde debe de estar el problema

```
function validacioon() {

     let cedulaa = document.getElementById("cedulaaa").value; 

     var arrays = datos.forEach(function (elementos) {
      if (elementos === cedulaa) {
        return true;}
      else{
      return false;}
     })
     return arrays;}
```

```
 var validar = validacioon()

 if (validar === true){

alert("correcto")};
```

lo que me gustaria saber es porque no me valida para asi mostrarme el alert, tengo rato analizando pero no observo lo que me falta para que me valide cuando meta la cedula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes simplificar la búsqueda con un `Array.includes()` Te recomendaría dos funciones, una para controlar el click y otra para hacer la validación.

```js
function validacion() {
  const datos  = ["25000111", "21000222", "22444333", "23222333", "25111222"];
  const cedula = document.getElementById("cedula").value;
  
  // Haz una busqueda en tu arreglo, esto regresa un bool
  return datos.includes( cedula );
}

function esValido() {
  const mensaje = validacion() ? 'Si existe' : 'No está registrada';
  console.log( mensaje );
}
```

```html
<input id="cedula">
<button onClick="esValido()">Validar</button>
```

Comment: gracias amigo si me soluciono el problema :)